# One dimensional integration that Mathematica cannot do

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, mathematica

I want to evaluate $$\int_{a+b-c}^s\,\text{d}x\, \frac{(-x+ab/c)^{\epsilon}}{(x+c-a-b)^{\epsilon+1} (a-x)},$$ where $a,b,c,\epsilon$ are real numbers, and to be treated as constants in the integration. I put this into mathematica and an hour later it is still attempting to evaluate it so I aborted the calculation. I was just wondering if it is possible to make headway on the calculation analytically?

I tried partial fractions which gave a rewriting of the form $$\frac{1}{c-b}\int_{a+b-c}^{s} \text{d}x\, \frac{(-x+ab/c)^{\epsilon}}{(x+c-a-b)^{\epsilon}} \left(\frac{1}{x+c-a-b} + \frac{1}{a-x}\right)$$ $$ = \frac{1}{c-b}\left(\int_{a+b-c}^{s} \text{d}x\, \frac{(-x+ab/c)^{\epsilon}}{(x+c-a-b)^{\epsilon+1}} + \int_{a+b-c}^{s} \text{d}x\, \frac{(-x+ab/c)^{\epsilon}}{(x+c-a-b)^{\epsilon}} \frac{1}{a-x}\right)$$ but this probably did not help.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $t?$

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a typo that I've carried through in the copy and pasting. $t$ should be $c$.I'll edit my post. Thanks

Comment: OK. Thnx....and $s?$

Comment: Upon evaluation of these integrals I want to get a function of $s,a,b,c$ and $\epsilon$. $s$ is also another real number. Thanks

Comment: Mathematica generated several answers for me, depending on exactly what [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) I used. This is why it's typically a good idea to include your code when asking a question about a a computer language.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Many thanks for your reply, could you perhaps post what Mathematica gave you in an answer? I didn't input any assumptions in my attempt but, since the problem comes from a physical calculation, I am hoping that in the result I have something obeying $\epsilon, c, s,b < 0$ and $a>0$. Thanks!

Comment: I tried again with the input  ``Integrate[(-x + a*b/t)^e/(x + t - a - b)^e/(x + t - a - b)/(a - x), {x, a + b - t, s}, Assumptions -> e < 0]'' in Mathematica but this does not generate anything for me, or at least its taking a while.

Comment: Any help please? I tried again today and my machine still can't do it.